# NoSuchFieldException when using SugarORM (big dependency)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex, sugarorm

When I call `SugarRecord.listAll(SignInData.class)` I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mFlags in class Landroid/service/media/MediaBrowserService$Result; (declaration of 'android.service.media.MediaBrowserService$Result' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
    at android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompatApi24.<clinit>(MediaBrowserServiceCompatApi24.java:36)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClass(ReflectionUtil.java:274)
    at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClasses(ReflectionUtil.java:258)
    at com.orm.SchemaGenerator.createDatabase(SchemaGenerator.java:45)
    at com.orm.SugarDb.onCreate(SugarDb.java:28)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
    at com.orm.SugarDb.getDB(SugarDb.java:38)
    at com.orm.SugarRecord.getSugarDataBase(SugarRecord.java:35)
    at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:201)
    at com.orm.SugarRecord.listAll(SugarRecord.java:127)
```

I use SugarORM in version 1.5 and have another dependency with many transitive dependencies. I already excluded some of them, so the gradle build & installation no longer complains about too many methods. But I needed to enable jumboMode, but no minifyEnabled.

I don't know if anything of this has to do with my error, but since it reffers to a dex-file, this is my only clue so far.

**EDIT**

I excluded even more transitive dependencies so I no longer need the jumboMode but it is still the same error.

Comment: If you're still having an issue, please provide your code that is causing this, and your model

Answer (score 0):

In My case I got this Exception because there is **no data** table. and trying to retrieve data from table. Just insert some data first.(Sorry don't know the root cause of this Exception )